# For any natural numbers $n> 1$ and $k, n\nmid (kn+1)$

Tags: divisibility

I am stuck on how to begin this proof. My intuition tells me I need to do something with odd and even. For example, If $n$ and $k$ are even then their product is even and adding $1$ will make it odd and not divisible by $n$. I can show all the scenarios but I'm unsure if it work. Also it might be possible to do it by showing there's a remainder but I'm in the process of learning that topic so that's unclear.

Any tips or suggestions on how to start this?

Comment: Assume, to the contrary, that $n\,|\,(kn+1)$.  Deduce that $n\,|\,1$.

Comment: For $n=1$, it does divide.

Comment: I am pretty sure i wrote n>1. Sorry for the confusion that is what i meant.

Comment: @lulu is it enough to say that since kn is a multiple of n therefore there is a remainder of 1 and n l 1 hence contradiction. Is there a general rule that if n l kn +q then q must be divisible by n? makes sense intuitively.

Comment: No need to rely on intuition.  if $n\,|\,(nk+1)$ then $nk+1=mn$ for some $m\in \mathbb N$.  But then $1=n\times(m-k)$.

Comment: Oh okay that makes a lot of sense. I wrote down that equation but didn't rearrange so i didn't see it. Thanks!

Comment: Another way: $\ k\,\color{#0a0}n + \color{#c00} 1\,$ divided by $\,\color{#0a0}n\,$ has quotient $\,k\,$ & remainder $\color{#c00} 1,\, $ by $\ 0 \le 1 < n.\,$  If it was divisible by $\,n\,$ it would have remainder $\,0\,$ (this uses the *uniqueness* of the remainder in the Division Algorithm).